# How to reset Jenkins email extension plugin sender configuration?

Tags: jenkins, automated-tests, jenkins-plugins, email-ext, jenkins-email-ext

I am using [email-ext plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/email-ext/) to send build status mails to the recipients . Currently , it shows sender as my personal email even though I've changed system admin email address and restarted jenkins multiple times.

**Is it there any custom method to change that or reset the configuration of plugin ?**

I've deleted jenkins cache too.

Answer (score 0):

Worst case, shutdown Jenkins, locate the config.xml inside Jenkins directory structure, and change the value there, then restart Jenkins

Comment: which value to change in config.xml ?

Answer (score 0):

This is [JENKINS-63846](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-63846), a regression introduced in `email-ext` 2.71. I will release a fix for this bug soon.